# How to make arrows on both sides of a box using css

Tags: css

I want to make a rectangle with arrows on both sides.
I have the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7wegxh4v/ .
Here is my css

```
<body>
<div id="arrowbox"></div>
</body>



#arrowbox
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

It now shows a green rectangle. I want to add two equilateral triangle triangles of green color at both ends. How can I do that using css? Any idea?

Comment: Look into using pseudo elements to create CSS triangles.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but I see no effort on your part other than creating a simple rectangle.

Comment: [How do CSS triangles work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work)

Comment: Instead of just adding triangles how can I make the a single shape containing left triangle then box then right triangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (using Pseudo-elements):

**CSS**

```
#arrowbox
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:100px;
    position: relative;
}

#arrowbox:after {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: #008000;
    border-width: 25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

#arrowbox:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #008000;
    border-width: 25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7wegxh4v/10/)**